# Scope of index in jQuery UI dialog callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to write a function that dynamically generates a Dialog widget with buttons from a list of pairs of labels and callback functions passed as an argument to the generating function.

```
function generateDialog(title, message, options) {

    var html = '<div id="dialog">' + message + '</div>';
    $("#dialog-container").append(html);

    var buttons = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        buttons[options[i][0]] = options[i][1];
    }

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        buttons: buttons
    });

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");

}
```

which I would call like this

```
options = []
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    options.push(["Option " + i, function() { alert('Option ' + i + ' was chosen'); }]);
}
generateDialog('Select option', 'Please choose option', options);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The labels are working fine, but the callback functions are not referencing the correct index.

Anyone know how to fix this, or know another way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I had to use another function to generate the callback functions in order to lose the reference to the index.

```
function genFunction(i) {
    return function () { alert('Option ' + i + ' was chosen'); };
}

options = []
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    options.push(["Option " + i, genFunction(i)]);
}
generateDialog('Select option', 'Please choose option', options);
```